# .htaccess modification

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using direct paths for downloading files from my site. the link is something like this

http://www.site.com/download.php?dir1/dir/dir3/file.doc

i want to wrap it with mod rewite rules so that only below link should be appeared

http://www.site.com/download

file, dir and dir3 are variable.
what i'hv to do in my .htaccess file?? Any Idea??

Comment: The `mod_rewrite` docs are [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html). Give it a shot and report errors here and people will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple redirect would be:

```
RewriteRule ^http://www.site.com/download/(.*)/?$ http://www.site.com/download.php?dir1/dir/dir3/$1 [NC,L]
```

This will take any request for something in the 'artificial' download directory and route it to the real location.

You can add more complex rules stripping out filetypes etc depending on your needs, or redirecting a 'name' to a filename etc etc..

e.g:

```
RewriteRule ^http://www.site.com/download/pdf/(.*)/?$ http://www.site.com/download.php?dir1/dir/dir3/$1.pdf [L,NC]
```

This would have an artificial PDF folder containing a filename ex the extension, routing to a .pdf doc....you can shape the redirect any way you like really...depends on the format you prefer

Comment: sorry i did'nt mention that the directory dir and dir3 are also variable directories.

Comment: If they are variables, they also need to be passed...meaning you will end up sending the same information...it doesnt seem like the logic is correct here. You will eaither have to store paths in a DB then pass the file ID via htaccess to a PHP output file...or simply pass in htaccess leaving effectively the original structure

Answer (score 0):

Not specific question. What is `dir1/dir/dir3/file.doc` means? If you want to get `http://www.site.com/download.php?dir1/dir/dir3/file.doc`, when you go to `http://www.site.com/download` do the next things in your .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^download/(.*)/?$ download.php?dir1/dir/dir3/file.doc [L]
```